# Amplifier circuit doesn't work (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: amplifier, dac

I'm trying to amplify a 0-5V DC signal (created bij a DAC) to a high voltage signal. I'm trying to do this via a Class A amplifying circuit (as advised by others before). For one reason or the other I'm still doing something wrong:

For now I'm using a BC550 transistor (B-E, on voltage: 0.6V, saturation voltage 1.1V). I built the following circuit:

[image: Schematic]

I'm using R3 and R4 to create a voltage of ± 0.6 volt over R4 (to reach the on-voltage), then use R5 and R6 to lower the sine signal to 0- 0.5V (to not go over the saturation value). So if I'm right, the base voltage should alternate between 0.6 and 1.1 and be exactly in the active area of the transistor. So should result on a \$V_{out}\$ sine of 1 - ±19 volt (measured over \$V_{out}\$ - GND).

This is not happening so I'm doing something wrong. But don't know what. Do I not understand the working of this circuit? And what should I change?

[image: Oscilloscope ex. 1]

[image: Oscilloscope ex. 2]

Comment: Have you tried simulating it? Measuring values with an osciliscope? What does happen, even measured with a multimeter? Do you actually want to amplify DC? It's possible that your coupling capacitor + resistors are filtering much of the signal out.

Comment: I have tried to measure every point in the circuit, but could not find a reasonable explanation for what I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you need about 0.5 to 1V on the emitter which means 1.2 to 1.7v on the base. Simple inspection tells me that 1k for R4 is too low and this is confirmed by your belief that it should have 0.6V across it. Try something like 2k7 for R4. This should give you: -

\$20 volts\times\dfrac{2700}{30000+2700} volts\$ = 1.65 volts

This will give you about 1V on the emitter and there will be a current thru R2 of 1mA. This will translate to a volt drop across the collector resistor (R1) of about 10V and this is about right for quiescent operating conditions on a 20 volt rail.

If you are really using 100 Hz as the input you might want to make C2 a bit bigger. At 100Hz it has an impedance of over 1500 ohms and this might be too high given the resistors R4 and R3.

Answer (score 2):

To the right of the coupling capacitor is a standard common emitter with degeneration circuit.  The problem is that don't have the transistor biased correctly.  This is because you haven't taken into account the voltage across R2 due to emitter current.

It's easy to show that the bias equation for this circuit is:

$$I_C = \dfrac{V_{BB} - V_{BE}}{\frac{R_{BB}}{\beta}+ \frac{R_2}{\alpha}} $$

where

$$V_{BB} = 20V \frac{R_4}{R_4 + R_3} = 20V \frac{1k}{1k + 30k} = 0.645V$$

$$R_{BB} = R_3||R_4 = 30k||1k= 968 \Omega $$

Since \$V_{BE}\$ is typically in the range of 0.65V to 0.75V, your \$V_{BB}\$ is *much* too low.

Let's say you would like \$I_C = 1mA\$.  Then, with \$R_2 = 1k\Omega\$, the emitter voltage will be approximately 1V.

Thus, the numerator in the bias equation will need to be *more than 1V*.

Assuming \$V_{BE} = 0.7V\$, choose \$V_{BB} = 1.8V\$

Keeping the 30k resistor, change \$R_4 \approx 3k\Omega\$

Now, feed this back into the bias equation to obtain  (assuming \$\beta=99\$):

$$I_C = \dfrac{1.82 - 0.7}{\frac{2.73k}{99}+ \frac{1k}{0.99}} = 1.08mA $$

This will give \$V_C = 9.2V\$.

Now this isn't optimum and there other considerations but this should get you off on the right foot.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will give it a shot. I do have an additional question. In the last equation you have Rbb at 2.73k should this be the 968 or do I miss something?

Comment: ( got it, 2.73 is the result of 30k||3K) :)

Comment: Hi Alfred, 

I got the circuit up and running and in seems to work: first picture above. I'm just not really happy with the amplitude. I hoped it would be amplified a more. 

However, when i replaced R5 with 1k. I got the result on the second image. Although it is clipping on the bottom, the signal if way more amplified and going from ±2.5 volts to 20 volts. But i'm not sure why this happens. Maybe you know?

Second question is if i can drive anything with the Vout? Or does everything change if i start drawing current from Vout? 

I'd want to copy this to 100V so i cant use a cheap opamp

Thx

Comment: @user31440, I'll be on the road until Sunday evening.  I'll take a look at your 'scope traces then.

Comment: Hi Alfred, Did you have a chance to have a look at the scope traces? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ruben, first of all, I'm not sure why you have the voltage divider composed of R5 & R6.  Why would you attenuate a signal before amplifying it?

Comment: im working with a 0-5v signal which i have to bring back to a 0-0.5v signal, since that's the active area of the transistor

Comment: @Ruben, you're not reasoning properly about the circuit and, in particular, the operation of the transistor.  I can't address your misconceptions in a comment.  Perhaps I'll edit my answer after I've thought a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi alfred, i'm sorry if i'm not totally clear about what i want to achieve (i'm not an expert when it comes to electronics). But my basic goal is to amplify a 0-5v dc sine wave signal to a 0-110V dc sine wave signal. If there are other and better ways to do it i'm more than willing to try them.